# Modification of Melkman's algorithm for the convex hull

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, polygons, convex-hulls

I am using Melkman's algorithm for the convex hull of simple polygons, which is a gem.

In addition to the convex hull itself, I need to know what are the contact points, i.e. the vertices that are the endpoints of edges that were not in the original polygon (red points/blue edges in the figure).

I can find these points by comparing the initial polygon to the convex hull in linear time, but I was wondering if a simple modification of Melkman's algorithm could produce these points as a byproduct.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the *indices* of the vertices, not the *points*.

Green edges correspond to consecutive indices.
Blue bridges correspond to jumps.

Take care to handle $n \to 1$ as green.

Comment: Right, then it suffices to find the discontinuities in the indexing. Simple as that. Thanks.

Comment: If I am right, I need to way until the polygon is completely processed, as the last edge can invalidate all the hull edges so far.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I think so, yes.